# Using Varnish with Zope

Tags: varnish, zope, varnish-vcl, zodb

Is there anyway Varnish can be used on a Zope website that authenticates every request from the browser ? The docs mention that cookies if present Varnish will not cache anything. But Zope won't render response for any request without cookie authentication.

Comment: Look at docs and VCL examples from the Plone community.  There are plenty of cases where authenticated pages are not cached (hit_for_pass is usually used on any request with Set-Cookie or private cache control).   You have not indicated what you want to cache, or what your application does.  Assuming what you want to cache is static resources, possibly some file/BLOB resources, not personalized pages, you should be able to cache them with the right VCL and the right cache headers set on delivery (e.g. plone.app.caching sets appropriate headers for Plone, do something likewise).

Comment: I do want to cache the static resources like css, js & img files but they also need authentication before fetch.